# Getting Incorrect syntax near ',' error in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am running this query using SQL Query Analyzer in SQL Server 2000:

```
create table TABLENAME(
        DBID_ bigint not null,
        CLASS_ varchar(255) not null,
        DBVERSION_ integer not null,
        KEY_ varchar(255),
        CONVERTER_ varchar(255),
        HIST_ bit,
        EXECUTION_ bigint,
        TASK_ bigint,
        LOB_ bigint,
    DATE_VALUE_ timestamp,
        DOUBLE_VALUE_ double,
        CLASSNAME_ varchar(255),
        LONG_VALUE_ bigint,
        STRING_VALUE_ varchar(255),
        TEXT_VALUE_ longvarchar,
        EXESYS_ bigint,
        primary key (DBID_)
    );
```

But an error occurs:

> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Line 12: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: That isn't SQL Server dialect

Comment: Looks like longvarchar is a [GeneXus data type](http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?LongVarChar+Data+Type,)

Comment: longvarchar could be a user defined data type

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the datatype of `double` on the `DOUBLE_VALUE_` column. You need to change it to a different datatype

You are also using a datatype of `longvarchar` on column `TEXT_VALUE_` which is invalid:

It is also very likely that you need to replace `timestamp` with `datetime`. Based on the corresponding column's name (`DATE_VALUE_`), you seem to mistake `timestamp` for a type that has something to do with, well, timestamps, [which it doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
create table TABLENAME(
        DBID_ bigint not null,
        CLASS_ varchar(255) not null,
        DBVERSION_ integer not null,
        KEY_ varchar(255),
        CONVERTER_ varchar(255),
        HIST_ bit,
        EXECUTION_ bigint,
        TASK_ bigint,
        LOB_ bigint,
        DATE_VALUE_ timestamp, -- consider changing this to datetime
        DOUBLE_VALUE_ double, -- change this to another datatype -- use float
        CLASSNAME_ varchar(255),
        LONG_VALUE_ bigint,
        STRING_VALUE_ varchar(255),
        TEXT_VALUE_ longvarchar,  -- change this datatype -- varchar(8000) or text
        EXESYS_ bigint,
        primary key (DBID_)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you .. I have a sql which I am suppose to execute in SQL server 2000. I will rectify the script as told

Comment: `varchar(max)` does not exist in SQL 2000 use `varchar(8000)` (biggest  varchar) or `Text`

Comment: @Magnus thanks, fixed. I don't have a SQL 2000 instance to test on. :)

Answer (score 0):

`double` is not a valid date type.  Try `real`, or `float`.

> float: Floating precision number data with the following valid values:
>   -1.79E + 308 through -2.23E - 308, 0 and 2.23E + 308 through 1.79E + 308.
>
> real : Floating precision number data with the following valid values:
>   -3.40E + 38 through -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 through 3.40E + 38.

[MSDN Page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)